# Unique minimal generator set to any numerical semigroup?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, integers, semigroups

Let $M$ be a multiplicatively closed set of natural numbers greater than one. $L\subseteq M$ is a *generator set* of $M$ if for any $m\in M$ there exist numbers $l_1\leq l_2\leq\cdots\leq l_k$ in $L$ such that $m=\prod l_i$. A *minimal* generator set of $M$ is a generator set $L$ such that for all $l\in L$ it holds that $l=l_1 \cdots l_n\implies n=1$ for all $l_1,\dots,l_n\in L$.

I want to know if a minimal generator set of $M$ has to be unique.

Comment: You surely mean *there exist numbers $l_1\leq l_2\leq\cdots\leq l_k$ in $L$*. How about taking $l_1 = \min M$, then $l_2 = \min(M \setminus \{l_1^h : h \ge 1\})$, $l_3 = \min(M \setminus \{l_1^k l_2^k : h, k \ge 1\})$, etc.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: then it remain to prove that this produce a unique minimal set of generators. And, the generator set can of cause be infinite.

Comment: The Caranti generators are irreducible in $M$ (they cannot be factored in $M$), since each new one is chosen exactly when it cannot be generated by smaller elements of $M$. It follows that they must belong to any generating set. This proves that they constitute the unique minimal generating set.

Comment: @KeithKearnes: ok, I will try to understand.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: thank you!

Comment: @KeithKearnes: you are right, thanks!