# Construction of generator set for intersection of numerical semigroups

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, semigroups

As in [Unique minimal generator set to any numerical semigroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077157/unique-minimal-generator-set-to-any-numerical-semigroup)

Let $M$ be a multiplicatively closed set of natural numbers greater than one. $L\subseteq M$ is a *generator set* of $M$ if for any $m\in M$ there exist numbers $l_1\leq l_2\leq\cdots\leq l_k$ in $L$ such that $m=\prod l_i$. A *minimal* generator set of $M$ is a generator set $L$ such that for all $l\in L$ it holds that $l=l_1 \cdots l_n\implies n=1$ for all $l_1,\dots,l_n\in L$.

Let $\mathcal G(l_1,\dots,l_n)$ be the semigroup generated by 
$\{l_1,\dots,l_n\}$. In the comments to the question above a unique minimal generator set $\{l_1,l_2,\dots \}$ is constructed for a numerical semigroup $M$ with a generator set $L$:

$l_1=\min L$
$l_{n+1}=\min(L\setminus\mathcal G(l_1,\dots,l_n))$

If $M$ and $M'$ are numerical semigroups with generator sets $L$ and $L'$, then 
$M\cdot M'=\{m\cdot m'|m\in M\wedge m'\in M'\}$ is a semigroup with generator set $L\cup L'$.

Also $M\cap M'$ is a semigroup and my question is: is it possible to generally construct a generator set for $M\cap M'$, from (eventually minimal) generator sets $L$ and $L'$?

Comment: Out of curiosity: In which topics are these called groupoids? I have never encountered any text calling them anything but semigroups (with groupoids being a type of category).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You are right, thanks! I will edit.